# usage of Iterable[String] vs. List[String] in Scala

Tags: scala, iterable

I was reading a Scala script and found massive usage of `Iterable[string]`.
For example:

```
def wordFeatures(words: Iterable[String]): Iterable[Vector] = words.map(w => Try(word2vecModel.transform(w))).filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
```

I am new to Scala and I would just use `List[String]`, `Array[String]`, `Vector[String]`, the collections directly rather than `Iterable[String]`, `Iterable[Int]`.

I guess maybe using iterable would reduce memory usage and the possibility of OOM, but not sure.

So, the question is: what's the advantage of passing iterables rather than the collections as the arguments of functions in Scala?

Comment: If your method accepts `List[Int]` then it will **only** accept `List[Int]`. If it accepts `Iterable[Int]` then it will accept `List[Int]`, and `Vector[Int]`, and `LazyList[Int]`, and many others.

Comment: @jwvh, cool, very clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This convenient because `Iterable` is one of most top level in scala collections hierarchy. Accepting `Iterable` functions can handle most number specific types independent of concrete realization, functions don't need to know it. It's enough to know what collection can be iterated. So, it's not about memory optimization, it's just implementation of Barbara Liskov substitution principle.
helpfull links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_subtyping
- [collections hierarchy](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html)